# Getting the default location from ssh-keygen?

Tags: applescript, ssh-keygen

When using ssh-keygen if you don't specify a default directory the default directory is shown:

```
Enter file in which to save the key (/Users/username/.ssh/id_rsa):
```

I need to get the path and file name, "/Users/monkeypunch/.ssh/id_rsa".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
to getDefaultKeyPath()
    try
        do shell script ("ssh-keygen")
    on error response
        set oldDelim to AppleScript's text item delimiters
        set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {"(", ")"}
        set defaultKeyPath to text item 2 of response
        set AppleScript's text item delimiters to oldDelim
    end try
    return defaultKeyPath
end getDefaultKeyPath
```

getDefaultKeyPath() will return `/Users/monkeypunch/.ssh/id_rsa`.